# std::vector<bool> initialization returns `expected a type specifier`

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a bool vector as a private parameter of a class and the only method that works is this:

```
class S
{
    std::vector<bool> _array{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
};
```

I have found online a nice way of initializing a `vector` and I have tried using it:

```
class S
{
    private:
      std::vector<bool> _array(24, false);
};
```

but it returns `expected a type specifier` for both `24` and `false`;

What do you think ?

Comment: Also important to note: `std::vector<bool>` is not a normal `std::vector`, it's a specialization that stores `bool` values in a space-compact way.

Comment: `std::vector<bool> _array = std::vector<bool>(24, false);` actually works for me. I don't know why VSC wouldn't let me compile before...

Comment: In the future please don't describe your code, *show* it instead. Preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can place `std::vector<bool> _array(24, false);` anywhere in the class and it returns `expected a type specifier`. The fix was to use it like this: `std::vector<bool> _array = std::vector<bool>(24, false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do (with parents)

```
std::vector<bool> _array = std::vector<bool>(24, false); // size is 24
```

With `{}`, you would use another constructor to take the whole list of item:

```
std::vector<bool> _array = std::vector<bool>{24, false}; // 24 for `true` but narrowing conversion
```

Syntax

```
std::vector<bool> _array (24, false); // Not allowed for member initialization
```

but you could use it in constructor

```
struct S
{
    std::vector<bool> _array;
    S() : _array(24, false) {}
    // ...
};
```

Comment: `std::vector<bool> _array = std::vector<bool>(24, false);` works fine now. I don't know why VSC didn't let me compile before.

Answer (score 1):

Inside classes or structures, definitions like

```
std::vector<bool> vect(24, false);
```

are considered ***function*** declarations.

Member inline initialization is only allowed to use *uniform initialization* with curly-braces `{}`, or "assignment" syntax as shown in [the answer from Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859545/440558).

Comment: And the one of the fixes is this: `std::vector<bool> _array = std::vector<bool>(24, false);`